# Java - ArrayList<Integer> as Parameter...?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I would like to know how to create a method which takes an ArrayList of Integers (ArrayList) as a parameter and then display the contents of the ArrayList?

I have some code which generates some random numbers and populates the ArrayList with the results, however I keep having errors flag up in eclipse when attempting to create this particular method.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public void showArray(ArrayList<Integer> array){

    return;

}
```

I know that it is very basic, but I am unsure exactly how to approach it - could it be something like the following?

```
public void showArray(ArrayList<Integer> array){

    Arrays.toString(array);

}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a learning exercise. I'll give you a few hints:

- Your method is named showArray, but an `ArrayList<T>` is of type `List<T>`, and is not an array. More specifically it is a list that is implemented by internally using an array. Either change the parameter to be an array or else fix the name of the method.
- Use an interface if possible instead of passing a concrete class to make your method more reusable.
- Minor point: It may be better to have your method return a String, and display the result outside the method.

Try something like this:

```
public void printList(List<Integer> array) {
    String toPrint = ...;
    System.out.println(toPrint);
}
```

You can use a loop and a StringBuilder to construct the toPrint string.

Comment: Good points about the method/parameter name and the use of List over ArrayList, but he asks for a function to "display the contents", not return the contents as a String.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why `System.out.println( array );` wouldn't work for you?

Output will be like:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I initially tried this, and even though it compiled correctly, I was unable to get the main method to invoke/call showArray...could somebody please tell me how to have the main method call showArray?  I have tried every possibility that I could think of but sadly, to no avail.  Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html will help?

Comment: Thank you, mjg123.  I took a look at the website but unfortunately nothing on there worked for me.  Do you (or anybody else) have another suggestion that I could attempt?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to print the array items, try

```
public void showArray(ArrayList<Integer> array){

 for(int arrayItem : array)
 {
    System.out.println(arrayItem);
 }

}
```

Answer (score -5):

This sounds like someone wants us to do their homework. You don't have to return anything if you are just displaying it, and if the method has a void return type. I don't know exactly what you want but is it something along the lines of System.out.println(array.elementAt(index))? then you would need a loop.